# Using Regex how to pull a word based on its position

Tags: regex

I am using Web ripper to pull information from my clients site and post it to a classifieds site.
The issue I am having is that the year model and make are all on one line and I need to seperate them.

example    2005 Acura MDX Touring 
I need to have it in 4 seperate fields

- year 2005
- make acura
- model mdx
- style touring

Using web ripper I am able to use Regex code in content transformation

so when I input

- `\w+`         I get 2005
- `\w(?<!\d)[\w'-]*`  I get Acura

What I need and would appreciate greatly is the proper regex code to get the third word and the forth word

Thank you very much

Comment: You know what your delimiters look like (namely, spaces) so you don't need a regex, you need to `split` the string.

Comment: ^^ he has a point. if its in the same format, then you can do this: `year, make, model, style = s.split()` I think.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response. The issue I have is that the software I am using only allows for REGEX code to transform the content

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you get "American Motors Jeep Grand Cherokee SUV"?  (Space is an unreliable delimiter.)

Comment: Then use a language that allows for splitting strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Web ripper, but you should be able to utilize capturing groups to make this fairly straightforward:

```
(\w+)[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+(\w+)[ \t]+(\w+)
```

Now year will be in capture group one (often `\1` or `$1`), make will be in capture group two, etc.

I used `[ \t]+` instead of `\s+` to make sure you won't grab newlines, if it is definitely only a single space you could simplify this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your script works to pull the entire script, but I need to divide the script into 4 seperate parts. Is it possible to edit your script to tell it skip a word

Comment: Based on the information [here](http://www.visualwebripper.com/forum/yaf_postst1037.aspx), it looks like you should be able to use that regex with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` to extract the fields you want.